# Conditionally toggling element in React-native overlap the element instead replace

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I have a header where i want to show menu or back Icon depending on the current page. so i am rendering the Icon conditionally like bellow

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
 
const HeaderContainer = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView forceInset={{top: 'never'}}>
      <View
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
          paddingLeft: 10,
          paddingRight: 10,
        }}>
      <View>
        {navigation.state.routeName !== 'Home' ? (
          <Icon
            name="chevron-back-sharp"
            size={30}
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.goBack();
            }}
          />
        ): (<Icon
          name="ios-menu"
          size={30}
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.toggleDrawer();
          }}
        />)}
      
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>

const CustomHeader = ({navigation}) => {
  return {
    header: (props) => <HeaderContainer {...props} />,
    headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#fff'},
    headerTintColor: '#000',
  };
};

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
    Cart: { screen: CartScreen },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      return CustomHeader(navigation);
    },
  },
);

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  { App: { screen: AppNavigator } },
  {contentComponent: DrawerContainer},
);

export default AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppDrawerNavigator);
```

But initially it is loading with only one Icon, i.e menu icon, but when i change the navigation, getting menu and back icon overlapped. please help me how can i fix this

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eRh5.png)

Comment: put backgroundColor to the view and see

Comment: Yes. this worked. but it is a hack

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would console.log the navigation right before returning the header to see how the routeName is changing. That might be happening because the initialRouteName is 'Home'.

Edit: you could store the routeName in a variable right before return and call it `isHome = navigation.state.routeName` and instead of having two icons between which you choose, put just one and change its props depending on `isHome`.

```js
<Icon
  name= !isHome ? "chevron-back-sharp" : "ios-menu"
  size={30}
  onPress={() => !isHome ? navigation.goBack() : navigation.toggleDrawer()}
 />
```

Another solution would be to have a param on Home screen, when it mounts

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.navigation.setParams({isHome: true})
 }
```

and then, `isHome = navigation.state && navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.isHome`

Comment: i have added a console like below
defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      console.log(navigation)
      return CustomHeader(navigation);
},

so. when i route from Home to Cart screen i got 2 console log entered. 

1. "state": {"key": "id-1612682328731-0", "routeName": "Home"}
2. "state": {"key": "id-1612682328731-1", "params": undefined, "routeName": "Cart"}

Comment: I have added a console like below

    defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      console.log(navigation)
      return CustomHeader(navigation);
    },
so. when i route from Home to Cart screen i got 2 console log entered.

"state": {"key": "id-1612682328731-0", "routeName": "Home"}
"state": {"key": "id-1612682328731-1", "params": undefined, "routeName": "Cart"}
Not getting why it is happening like this. Can you please help me out resolving this.

Comment: This is happening because the initialRouteName is 'Home'. I've edited the answer above, check it out if it works

Comment: when i set navigation.setParams({isHome: isHome}) before return in defaultNavigationOptions caused infinite render and got max depth reached error.

as a hack, for Icon i gave background color as white. it worked. defiantly not a good solution as both Icon renders on top of other, since background is set user cant see below one.


And what i observed is, when i colsole log the routeName, whereever i change the route, it prints 2 times. like when i route from Home to Cart Screen. it print like

Home,  Cart,  Home,  Cart